# How to map an array to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to map an arbitrary Ruby Array to a Hash.

Input:

```
['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
```

(The array will have between zero and three elements.)

Output:

```
{ foo1: 'bar1', foo2: 'bar2', foo3: 'bar3' }
```

I'm looking for the most elegant solution.

Comment: @coreyward Way to close this question without even comparing it to the other answer. My input is not an array of key-value pairs but whatever.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Where are `:foo1`, `:foo2` and `:foo3` supposed to come from? Is the code supposed to create a symbol for each element in the input array? Your question needs to state where they originate or why.

Comment: @theTinMan I'd say that's obvious from the question.

Comment: @BarryFruitman Hi Barry, I did consider that, but ultimately ruled that the community would not benefit from addressing this question again (there are over a dozen similar) simply to assist you in understanding. You're welcome to ask again, but first please use search, address how your needs are different, and share *what you have tried already*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-zip).

> foo.zip(bar).to_h

```
irb(main):003:0> [:foo1, :foo2, :foo3].zip(['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']).to_h
=> {:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2", :foo3=>"bar3"}
```

---

```
irb(main):004:0> b=['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
=> ["bar1", "bar2", "bar3"]
irb(main):005:0> f=[:foo1, :foo2, :foo3]
=> [:foo1, :foo2, :foo3]
irb(main):006:0> f.zip(b).to_h
=> {:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2", :foo3=>"bar3"}
irb(main):007:0> f.zip(b[0..2]).to_h
=> {:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2", :foo3=>"bar3"}
irb(main):009:0> f.zip(b[0..1]).to_h
=> {:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2", :foo3=>nil}
irb(main):010:0> f.zip(b[0..0]).to_h
=> {:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>nil, :foo3=>nil}
irb(main):011:0> f.zip([]).to_h
=> {:foo1=>nil, :foo2=>nil, :foo3=>nil}
```

Comment: Could also be: `%w[ bar1 bar2 bar3 ].map { |v| [ v.sub(/bar/, 'foo').to_sym, v ] }.to_h`